# jquery getting x values in sparkline

Tags: jquery, sparklines

I am new to jQuery and trying to make a sparkline. What I want is that when mouse points a point in the graph, **both x-value and y-value** should be seen. For now, only the y-values are visible.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sparkline").sparkline([1, 4, 6, 6, 8, 5, 3, 5], {
            type: 'line',
            height: '200',
            width: '240',
            barWidth: 20,
            barSpacing: 10,
            barColor: '#615c5a',
            fillColor:"white"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to add 'x' to the y display ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$('#sparkline').sparkline([1, 4, 6, 6, 8, 5, 3, 5], {
        type: 'line',
        height: '200',
        width: '240',
        barWidth: 20,
        barSpacing: 10,
        barColor: '#615c5a',
        fillColor:"white",          
        tooltipFormatter: function (sparkline, options, fields) {
         return "x: " + fields.x + " y: " + fields.y + "";
        }
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PfzXg/1231/)